# Trouble understanding the output of this OCaml code

Tags: reference, ocaml, ref

```
# let counter () = 
    let c = ref 0 in 
    fun () -> 
      let _ = c := !c + 1 in 
      !c ;; 
val counter : unit -> unit -> int = <fun> 

# let incCounter = counter () ;; 

# incCounter () ;; 
- : int = 1 

# incCounter () ;; 
- : int = 2
```

I do not understand why the line `let c = ref 0` doesn't get called again every time you call `incCounter () ;;`. It seems like the part `fun() ->...` just works on one reference of `c` each time you call `incCounter`.

Comment: One hint to the ref incrementing code: there is Pervasives.incr to do that, so line 4 can be rewritten as _incr c_ (okay, gsg said it...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `let c = ref 0` gets called everytime when `counter` is called (and not everytime `incCounter` is called).

The type of `counter` is `unit -> unit -> int`, meaning that `counter ()` returns a function of type `unit -> int`. If we say `let incCounter = counter ()`, we obtain a newly created function of type `unit -> int`. This function, in turn, modifies a reference that was constructed before by the call `counter ()`.

That said, the purpose of `counter ()` is to construct a new counter that can afterwards be incremented.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Each time you call a particular function value, the same reference cell will be accessed. If you call `counter` again, you'll get a different function value that accesses a different reference cell.

Incidentally, `incr c` is a clearer way to express `let _ = c := c + 1 in ...`.